# What's the elegant way to make sure that values of dictionary are called or set in a specific location?

Tags: vb.net

```
  Private Shared Property _dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Get

        End Get
        Set(value As Dictionary(Of String, String))

        End Set
    End Property
```

The usual way, if it's not a dictionary, is to turn the variable into property. Then we can put breakpoint in set and get.

The thing is setting a dictionary as property will make the compiler think I need a set method to set the dictionary. I want a set method to set an item in the property.

I want to be able to replace spread occurrences of

```
 _dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol("key") = "value"
```

into a code I can set breakpoint too. How should I?

I suppose I can just create a normal sub and replace all occurrences of _dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol("key") = "value" into AssignCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbolWithKeyValue("key","value")

I wrote

```
  Function GetCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol(key As String) As String
        Return _dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol(key)
    End Function
    Sub AssignCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol(key As String, coinname As String)
        _dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol(key) = coinname
    End Sub
```

And then I will just manually all other occurrences of `_dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol`. Then I can put breakpoints in `AssignCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol` if I see `_dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol` get assigned wrong value.

The problem with this technique is there isn't really anyway to enforce it automatically. I just have to go through the code and replace that one by one.

Are there more elegant ways?

If `_dictOfCoinNameNameBasedOnMarketandSymbol` is not a dictionary then changing it to property with proper get and set value would do just fine. I don't even have to change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I may have initially misinterpreted the question. I will leave my original answer below for completeness but I will answer here based on my new understanding.

It seems to me that what you actually need is an indexed property that will wrap the `Dictionary`, e.g.

```vb
Public Class SomeClass

    Private Shared ReadOnly valuesByKey As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public Shared Property ValueByKey(key As String) As String
        Get
            Return valuesByKey(key)
        End Get
        Set
            valuesByKey(key) = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

You can now just get and set the `ValueByKey` property and never have direct access - read-only or otherwise - to the `Dictionary` object inside the class. You can also add whatever code you like before the `Return` statement in the getter and before or after the existing line of code in the setter.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

What you want is a `ReadOnly` property. That's exactly how collections are exposed throughout the .NET Framework, e.g. `Control.Controls`, `ComboBox.Items`, `DataSet.Tables`, `DataTable.Columns`, `DataTable.Rows`, etc, etc. In your case, that would look like this:

```vb
Public Shared ReadOnly Property CoinNamesByMarketAndSymbol As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

I've taken the liberty of giving that property a sensible name. Note that this is an auto-property, i.e. one where you don't explicitly specify a getter or setter. Without using an auto-property, the equivalent code would this:

```vb
Private Shared _coinNamesByMarketAndSymbol As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Public Shared ReadOnly Property CoinNamesByMarketAndSymbol As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Get
        Return _coinNamesByMarketAndSymbol
    End Get
End Property
```

Note that I have declared this property `Public`. I note that you have declared it `Private` but that seems to make little sense. What use could such a property be? If it should only be accessed internally then why would you not just use a field?

With the code above, you can now get the `Dictionary` from the property to get, add or remove items but you cannot replace the entire `Dictionary`, i.e. you can do this:

```vb
Dim coinName = SomeClass.CoinNamesByMarketAndSymbol(marketAndSymbol)

SomeClass.CoinNamesByMarketAndSymbol.Add(marketAndSymbol, coinName)
SomeClass.CoinNamesByMarketAndSymbol.Remove(marketAndSymbol)
```

But you cannot do this:

```vb
SomeClass.CoinNamesByMarketAndSymbol = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

Comment: It should be a private field. I just want a certain code to be called every time I assign a new value to the key'

Comment: @obfuscated, I think that I have misinterpreted your question. Having read the question again, I think that it is poorly worded, hence the misunderstanding. I will update my answer accordingly.